# Select rows having some prefix in hexa

Tags: sql, postgresql

Most of the questions related to prefixes are for string field. My case is a little bit different. A user should be able to browse products based on the serial numbers. Serial numbers are stored as integer. The user input is in hexa. The output should be rows having this input as a prefix but in hexa notation only.

For example, let's say I have `0x1000`, `0x100ab` and `0xa0000b` as BIGINT in my database.

The input `[0x]1` should output the first two while the input `[0x]a` should output the third one only.

I am flexible with the input (i.e. I can do manipulations in Python) before inserting the query in SQL.

Edit:

I use PostgreSQL but I do not know if it changes something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_hex()` to convert an integer to a hex representation (without the `0x` prefix). That string can then be used together with a `LIKE` condition:

```
where concat('0x', to_hex(serial_number)) like '0x1%';
```

or a bit simpler if you strip off the the `0x` prefix:

```
where to_hex(serial_number) like '1%';
```